# Angular escaping strings but not rendering html

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular and I have ngSanitize installed, linked and injected into my app.

I am using $sce in my controller as the data I am getting back from a remote json file is coming back as unescaped strings

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Property Location&lt;/b&gt
```

I can get this to now render but am now left with the html rendered on the page. I have used ng-bind-html="snippet" but it is not rendering and showing html tags on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more code or a fiddle may be?

Comment: Sorry..I cant get a fiddle...But its almost like I need to sanitize it twice...When I sanitize it I have html tags in the veiw..I then need to sanitize it again to render out the html tags